# jquery - promise/deferred on custom function returning early when multiple elements passed for animate()

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-animate

I have a scrollbar on a div that contains a sidebar menu.  I make various changes to this sidebar menu that affect its width/height using jquery animate().  After animation has finished I need to make a call to `App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);` to update scrollbar with these new width/height values if any.  I have a couple different scenarios this happens so I added promise ability to `sidebarHideSub()` which handles these changes.

**Usage 1 :**

Works perfectly fine.  It waits until both calls to `sidebarHideSub()` completed then calls `App.updatePerfectScrollbar` as it should.

```
...code above
parent.addClass('open');
//open the submenu
var p1 = sidebarHideSub(sub, false, 1000, 0).promise();
//get all the top links with submenus EXCEPT the one that was clicked
menu = $('#rsideleft').find('a.collapse').not($(this));
//remove the 'open' class on all menus except the one that was clicked
menu.parent().removeClass('open')
//close all the other submenus
var p2 = sidebarHideSub(menu.parent().find('.subMenu'), true, 1000, 0).promise();

//when finished
$.when(p1, p2).then(function() {
    console.log('update');
    App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);
});
...code below
```

**Usage 2 :**

This works fine as well.

```
...code above
parent.removeClass('open');
//close the submenu
sidebarHideSub(sub, true, 1000, 0).promise().then(function(){
    console.log('update');
    App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);
});
...code below
```

**Usage 3 :**

**Does not work correctly.**  This does not wait till animation has completed before the promise is executed.  I immediately see 'update' in my console when it starts the animation rather than after the animation has completed.  The only difference I can see between this and the two above it is the animation is happening on multiple elements.  `$('#rsideleft .subMenu')` can match multiple instances on the page whereas the ones above would only match one.  So, my guess is the promise is being returned immediately because one of the matched elements did not require any animation while others did?  That is really the only reason I can come up with although it is not the way I would expect it to behave.

```
...code above
if( $('body').hasClass('minimized') ) {
    sidebarHideSub($('#rsideleft .subMenu'), true, 1000, 0).promise().then(function(){
        console.log('update');
        App.updatePerfectScrollbar(psSidebar);
    });
}
...code below
```

**the function :**

```
function sidebarHideSub(el, action, speed, delay) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        
    if(action) {            
        el.delay(delay).animate({
            opacity: 'hide',
            height: 'hide'
        }, speed, function(){
            deferred.resolve(true);
        })
    } else {
        el.delay(delay).animate({
            opacity: 'show',
            height: 'show'
        }, speed, function(){
            deferred.resolve(true);
        })
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Any ideas on why this is behaving the way it does and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

So animate does run once for each when multiple elements are matched.  So, what I thought was happening... the promise was returned for a matched element immediately because it did not require any animation while other matched elements did.  The solution was to add a promise on the animation and return the other promise when the entire 'set' has completed animation - if that makes sense.

```
function sidebarHideSub(el, action, speed, delay) {

    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        
    if(action) {                
        el.delay(delay).animate({
            opacity: 'hide',
            height: 'hide'
        }, speed).promise().then(function() {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        })
    } else {
        el.delay(delay).animate({
            opacity: 'show',
            height: 'show'
        }, speed).promise().then(function() {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        })
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```